# jsf facelet persian character encoding error

Tags: jsf, encoding, filter

I develop a java application with jsf and eclispeLink with netbeans 7.3.1 but my character don't save correctly. I look at request variable and saw that my character are not correctly show in the request object.

My Jsf sample :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

    <ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="title">
            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.CreateTblAccessTitle}"></h:outputText>
        </ui:define>
        <ui:define name="body">
            <h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
                <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green" layout="table"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateTblAccessLabel_id}" for="id" />
                    <h:inputText id="id" value="#{tblAccessController.selected.id}" title="#{bundle.CreateTblAccessTitle_id}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateTblAccessRequiredMessage_id}"/>
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateTblAccessLabel_userName}" for="userName" />
                    <h:inputText id="userName" value="#{tblAccessController.selected.userName}" title="#{bundle.CreateTblAccessTitle_userName}" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateTblAccessLabel_userTypeId}" for="userTypeId" />
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="userTypeId" value="#{tblAccessController.selected.userTypeId}" title="#{bundle.CreateTblAccessTitle_userTypeId}" >
                        <f:selectItems value="#{tblUserTypeController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"/>
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateTblAccessLabel_formId}" for="formId" />
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="formId" value="#{tblAccessController.selected.formId}" title="#{bundle.CreateTblAccessTitle_formId}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateTblAccessRequiredMessage_formId}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{tblFormController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"/>
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateTblAccessLabel_activitesId}" for="activitesId" />
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="activitesId" value="#{tblAccessController.selected.activitesId}" title="#{bundle.CreateTblAccessTitle_activitesId}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateTblAccessRequiredMessage_activitesId}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{tblAccessActivitiesController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"/>
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <br />
                <h:commandLink action="#{tblAccessController.create}" value="#{bundle.CreateTblAccessSaveLink}" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <h:commandLink action="#{tblAccessController.prepareList}" value="#{bundle.CreateTblAccessShowAllLink}" immediate="true"/>
                <br />
                <br />
                <h:link outcome="/index" value="#{bundle.CreateTblAccessIndexLink}"/>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>

</html>
```

MY Filter to change encoding :

```
public class EncodingFilter implements Filter{

    private String encoding;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        encoding = filterConfig.getInitParameter("requestEncoding");
        if( encoding==null ) encoding="UTF-8";
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        httpRequest.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
        httpResponse.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
        chain.doFilter(httpRequest, httpResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
    }

}
```

My Template.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title><ui:insert name="title">Default Title</ui:insert></title>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/jsfcrud.css"/>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h1>
            <ui:insert name="title">Default Title</ui:insert>
        </h1>
        <p>
            <ui:insert name="body">Default Body</ui:insert>
        </p>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

My web.xml

```
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>business.EncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
                <param-name>requestEncoding</param-name>
                <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
            <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

what is the problem? how could i solve it?

Comment: Everthing looks okay at first glance (except of manipulation of `response` in the filter, that's totally unnecessary, I'd get rid of those lines; also the exception in `destroy()` is wrong, remove that whole line), so your problem is likely caused somewhere else. How exactly did you conclude that the characters are corrupted? Are you printing them using `System.out.println()` to IDE console or what? If so, are you sure that the console is in turn been configured to use UTF-8 to print those characters?

Comment: No I add a break point in my code and watch value of my class. The value is not correct in the request object. When i store value in my database directly with workbench it show correctly in explorer but when i save data with my form it is not correct

Comment: I create the same project in intellij idea with tomcat and hibernate and there is no problem in it. every thing is ok. does any one know waht is the prblem. my netbeans project application server is glassfish

Answer (score 0):

Every things look fine! You should check the following:

a) Check whether your Glassfish Resources has following inside :

```
<property name="useUnicode" value="true"/>
<property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF8"/>
```

b) Whether your database and the table are UTF-8 CHARCTER SET

for mysql use following code:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;

USE dbname;

ALTER TABLE tblname CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```